# Jquery funcion que permita a N numeros de inputs hacer incremento/decremento por medio de mousedown

Tags: jquery

tengo este script que permite incrementar/decrementar el value de un input arratrando hacia arriba y hacia abajo con el click presionado. Pero necesito hacerlo funcion para poder agregarle esta funcionalidad a cualquier input tambien con un minimo y un maximo de rango de valor https://jsfiddle.net/iLen/ggqzb27f/3/

```
var clicking = false;
    $('this').click(function () {
                clicking = false;
            });
            $('#change_value_up_down').mousedown(function () {
                clicking = true;
            });
            var i = 0;
            var y = 0;
            $(this).mousemove(function(my){
                if(clicking === false) 
                {
                    return false;
                }
                else
                {
                    // change value
                    if (my.pageY <= $('#change_value_up_down').offset().top + $('#change_value_up_down').css('width').replace('px', '')/10) 
                    {
                        y = parseInt($('#change_value_up_down').val()) +1 ;
                        $('.movestatus').text('plus');
                        }
                    else
                    {
                        y =  parseInt($('#change_value_up_down').val()) -1;
                        $('.movestatus').text('minus');
                        }
                    $('#change_value_up_down').val(parseInt(y));  
                    // Mouse click + moving logic here
                    //$('.movestatus').text('mouse moved ' + i);
                    i++;
                }
            });
            $(this).mouseup(function(e) {
                clicking = false;
                //e.stopPropagation();
            });
            $('.selector').mouseup(function(e) {
                i = 0;
            });
```

El codigo esta crudo, pero necesito que esto sea una funcion para hacerlo en cualquier input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var clicking = false;
$('.vamoAlSubibaja').mousedown(function() {
  clicking = true;  
});

$(document).mouseup(function() {
  clicking = false;  
})
var i = 0;
var y = 0;
$('.vamoAlSubibaja').mousemove(function(my) {
  if (clicking == false) {
    return
  } else {
    // change value
    if (my.pageY <= $(this).offset().top + $('.vamoAlSubibaja').css('width').replace('px', '') / 10) {
      y = parseInt($(this).val()) + 1;
      $('.movestatus').text('plus');
    } else {
      y = parseInt($(this).val()) - 1;
      $('.movestatus').text('minus');
    }
    $(this).val(parseInt(y));    
    i++;
  } 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<i>Only when the mouse moves up and down does
    the value change from the input
    (validate min y max)</i>
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<input type="text" value="5" class="vamoAlSubibaja" id="change_value_up_down" />
<input type="text" value="5" class="vamoAlSubibaja" id="change_value_up_down2" />

<!-- only ref -->
<span class="clickstatus"></span>
<span class="movestatus"></span>
```

Comment: Gracias por el momento funciona bien, es lo que necesitaba

Comment: de nada hermano, ya luego vemos para hacerlo funcionar correctamente en Google Chrome :D

Comment: hola @fredyfx te cuento que no funciona correctamente en Chrome :/ en firefox funciona bien pero en crome no incrementa si esta fuera del input